# Execute a function whenever a property of an observable changes in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a demo [application](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5884/) where all the list items are observables. To achieve this I have used the mapping plugin on the array from which the list is created.

```
this.allItems = ko.mapping.fromJS([
    {name:"Annabelle"},
    {name:"Vertie"},
    {name:"Charles"},
    {name:"John"}
]);
```

My question is - how to properly implement this kind of behavior in Knockout JS: whenever a property of an observable(any item of the list) changes a sort function is executed:

```
    this.sortList = function() {
    this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.name() > b.name();}).slice(0, 2));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare a view model class. Then, declare allItems as an observable array, but display to the user a different member, called say sortedItems, which should be a computed field. This computed field will use allItems internally, so KO will notice when allItems gets updated and will re-evaluate sortedItems too.

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
    {name:"Annabelle"},
    {name:"Vertie"},
    {name:"Charles"},
    {name:"John"}
]);

    this.sortedItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.allItems().sort(sortFunction);
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: This is not the exact thing I was looking for, but it was helpful and I was able to produce the application I wanted with the help of this answer. If anyone viewing this question in the future finds this useful - here is the result I wanted to achieve in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5885/) .